# How to generate an XML file

Tags: asp.net, xml

I need to create an  xml file here

```
bool result= false;
```

How to achieve this in ASP.NET with C# syntax. `result` is value that I need to add in the XML file.

I need to create an XML file under a folder with contents like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<user>
  <Authenticated>yes</Authenticated> 
</user>
```

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```
XmlTextWriter xtw = new XmlTextWriter(@"yourfilename.xml", Encoding.UTF8);

xtw.WriteProcessingInstruction("xml", "version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"");
xtw.WriteStartElement("user");
xtw.WriteStartElement("Authenticated");
xtw.WriteValue(result);
xtw.WriteEndElement();  // Authenticated
xtw.WriteEndElement();  // user

xtw.Flush();
xtw.Close();
```

Or if you prefer to build up your XML file in memory, you can also use the `XmlDocument` class and its methods:

```
// Create XmlDocument and add processing instruction
XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
xdoc.AppendChild(xdoc.CreateProcessingInstruction("xml", "version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\""));

// generate <user> element
XmlElement userElement = xdoc.CreateElement("user");

// create <Authenticated> subelement and set it's InnerText to the result value        
XmlElement authElement = xdoc.CreateElement("Authenticated");
authElement.InnerText = result.ToString();

// add the <Authenticated> node as a child to the <user> node
userElement.AppendChild(authElement);

// add the <user> node to the XmlDocument
xdoc.AppendChild(userElement);

// save to file
xdoc.Save(@"C:\yourtargetfile.xml");
```

Should work on any version of the .NET framework, if you have a `using System.Xml;` clause at the top of your file.

Marc

Answer (score 3):

```
XElement xml = new XElement("user",
                    new XElement("Authenticated","Yes"))
                );
xml.Save(savePath);
```

It works for .net 3 and above, but
 You can use XmlDocument for later versions

```
    XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();

    // Write down the XML declaration
    XmlDeclaration xmlDeclaration = xmlDoc.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0","utf-8",null);

    // Create the root element
    XmlElement rootNode  = xmlDoc.CreateElement("user");
    xmlDoc.InsertBefore(xmlDeclaration, xmlDoc.DocumentElement); 
    xmlDoc.AppendChild(rootNode);

    // Create the required nodes
    XmlElement mainNode  = xmlDoc.CreateElement("Authenticated");
    XmlText yesText= xmlDoc.CreateTextNode("Yes");
    mainNode.AppendChild(yesText);

    rootNode.AppendChild(mainNode);

    xmlDoc.Save(savePath);
```

You can use XmlWriter too as suggests @marc_s or at least you can store xml to the file like sting

```
using(StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(savePath))
{
sw.Write(string.Format("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\" ?>
<user><Authenticated>{0}</Authenticated></user>","Yes"));
}
```

Comment: i   did     not  find name  property like  XElement

Answer (score 1):

If you want to generate the XML and then give the user a choice to save the XML in their workstation, check the post below. It explains that process in detail.

[Generating XML in Memory Stream and download](http://willmtz.blogspot.com/2011/11/exporting-data-as-xml-in-memorystream.html)

Comment: Providing example code would guarantee that your post will be useful to future users. ;)